# get schema name

Tags: database, jdbc, sequence, sequences

can some one pls tell me how to get the 'schema name' for a particular 'sequence' using jdbc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are using Oracle DB.
If that's the case you can run the query given below via JDBC and get the column named sequence_owner for the Schema Name to which a sequence belongs to.

```
SELECT sequence_owner
  FROM all_sequences
 WHERE sequence_name = '<YOUR_SEQUENCE_NAME>'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select SCHEMA_NAME from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA
```

This is return all schema names.